# find the set of parametric equations through the point...

Tags: calculus

Now I've never asked a homework question here before as I usually like to do them myself - however this is a question that I can't figure out. The book examples and homework are somewhat similar but its never given the said line in forms of equations for the points  x=-7+2t etc. and none of the examples have this form either so it's a bit tough for me to figure out.

Any help?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because it is parallel to the lines, the vector is going in the direction of <2,3,3>. It's magnitude is arbitrary, so it can be any k<2,3,3> where k is any number. Also, it can be ofset from the point. For example, (6,8,5)-<2,3,3> can passes through (4,5,2). The answer is the first choice from the top.

Comment: so basically we found the equations for a second point on this problem on the line L? with v= (2,3,3) from the given sets of equations...........   oh i see -- they are parallel so the vectors should be pointing in the same direction, hence the parameters in the set of equations for the second point should be 2s 3s & 3s    -- is that correct?